# Are there reserved kwargs for python's dict constructor?

Tags: python

When using the kwarg-style dict initialization:

```
In [3]: dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
Out[3]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

for some reason, defining the key 'from' raises a syntax error:

```
In [4]: dict(to=0, from=1)
------------------------------------------------------------
   File "<ipython console>", line 1
     dict(to=0, from=1)
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is special about the key 'from'?  Are there any other reserved keys for the kwarg-style initialization?

I am using Python 2.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`from` is used in imports.

[Python Language Reference, §2.3.1, "Keywords"](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords)

Note that you can still use kwarg expansion to get them through though.

Comment: Since "explicit is better than implicit" ;) You can call a function that accepts kwargs, and pass a kwarg with a key of `'from'`, like so: `the_function(**{'from': 'a very silly place'})`.

Answer (score 3):

`from`, like a handful of other tokens, are keywords/reserved words in Python (`from` specifically is used when importing a few hand-picked objects from a module into the current namespace). You cannot use them as identifiers or anything (ultimately, kwargs are identifiers). It's simply not allowed, even when *in theory* it could disambiguated, to keep the parser simple and the people writing the parser sane ;)

Answer (score 2):

from is a keyword:

```
from threading import Thread
```

Python doesn't have context-sensitive keywords: A name is either a keyword, or can be used as an identifier. There used to be one exception: "as" used to be special-cased in import statements when it was first introduced, but has since been promoted to "full keyword".

Context-sensitive keywords would be a questionable feature. E.g. should

```
print=3
```

work or fail (it could be a syntactically incorrect print statement, or an assignment to a variable named print). Or, what about

```
def print(x):
    print x
print(3)
```

Should this define a function print? If so, is the last line a call?

Comment: I realize that `from` is a keyword.  I am surprised it is being interpreted as such in a kwarg expression.  You would think the parser would be smart enough to know the difference in this context.

Comment: @awesomo, keyword means it _always_ a keyword regardless of context

Comment: See my edit: there is a good reason keywords are not context-sensitive.

Comment: +1 for pointing out how much of a headache contextual keywords are.

Comment: @martin Thanks.  My intuition was that since the kwargs given to dict are transformed into strings that reserved words/keywords  as keys wouldn't be problematic in this context.  I guess this falls under "Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules."

Comment: kwargs are *always* converted to strings, and *always* make keys in a dictionary (namely, the kw dictionary). Calling the dict builtin is really no different.

Comment: @awesomo the key `'from'` is not problematic, but the text `from` in the source code is. The code is parsed, and `SyntaxError` s raised, **before** it runs (and the `kwargs` get converted into strings). `from` in this context causes a problem before there is a chance to make it not-a-problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can't use python keywords such as `from` in kwargs